# R classify data classIntervals automatic change of classification style

Tags: r

I'm building a maps with R. For this I need to classify data. I have a fixed range. I have a lot of feature, some of them, as on example fall within a small range of the classifier. During the classification R changes style = "fixed" to the "unique". How can this problem be solved?

```
library(classInt)

df <- c(8,6,5,7,7,6,5,5,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,7,7,7,
6,6,7,7,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5)

breaks <- c(-50, -26, -22, -17, -13, -10,  -6,  -3,   1,   6,  10,  50)
classIntervals(df, 11, style="fixed", fixedBreaks=breaks)

Warning messages:
1: In classIntervals(var = df, n = 11, style = "fixed", fixedBreaks = breaks) :
  n greater than number of different finite values\nn reset to number of different finite values
2: In classIntervals(var = df, n = 11, style = "fixed", fixedBreaks = breaks) :
  n same as number of different finite values\neach different finite value is a separate class
```

As a result, I get an incorrect classification.

```
style: unique
  one of 1 possible partitions of this variable into 4 classes
[4.5,5.5) [5.5,6.5) [6.5,7.5) [7.5,8.5] 
    3         2         3         2
```

I have another feature (for example) where classify works well.

```
df <- c(87,134,239,139,92,114,204,177,143,48,59,76,95,86,98,108,104,156,
173,88,86,62,1,38,26,35,39,45,47,51,58,58,141,161,81,57,33,4,19,18,18,28,31,
34,40,48,78,48,19,6,3,2,18,22,26,33,72,58,37,20,14,12,6,13,17,20,25,32,104,
84,47,48,49,6,5,5,7,9,11,14,18,26,29,27,32,36,71,68,65,59,48,16,9,8,10,
11,14,18,20,23)

breaks <- c(-1000, -600, -400, -200, 0, 100, 300, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1500)
class <- classIntervals(df, 11, style="fixed", fixedBreaks=breaks)
class

style: fixed
  one of 461,738,052,776 possible partitions of this variable into 11 classes
[-1000,-600)  [-600,-400)  [-400,-200)     [-200,0)      [0,100)    [100,300)    [300,400)    [400,600)    [600,800)   [800,1000)  [1000,1500] 
       0            0            0            0           86           14            0            0            0            0            0
```

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example with the desired result?

Comment: Roman, I added to the question a example in which the classification works well.

Comment: Note that `classIntervals` does not come with base R. Add what package the function comes from.

Comment: The function comes from the package **classInt**

Comment: How about `cut(df, breaks = breaks)`?

Comment: The problem is that the results of the calculations (inclassIntervals) I use for other function (findColours, the same package classInt), which does not accept the result of **cut**.